# invalid back reference in lookahead in c++ std::regex

Tags: c++, regex

It seems that c++ std::regex doesn't support back reference in lookahead. http://www.regular-expressions.info only says that c++ doesn't support lookbehind,foreward reference and nested reference. I also scanned c++14 standard and found nothing. Too little information about c++ std::regex on web.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    regex re("(a)xxx(?=\\1)");
    smatch matchs;
    string str {"axxxa"};
    if(regex_search(str,matchs,re)) {
        cout << "matched" << endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"not matched"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but with run error at:

```
regex re("(a)xxx(?=\\1)");
```

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: The expression contained an invalid back reference.

My gcc version:
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0

B.T.W. the same regex works in Nodejs:

```
var t = /(a)xxx(?=\1)/;
console.log(t.exec("axxxa"));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your MCVE works fine [here](https://ideone.com/rnfsUy) and in VS

Comment: That looks like a bug in the `libc++abi.dylib` implementation of the ECMAScript regex engine.  I'm seeing it also in `Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)` (Xcode 9.3).  You'll need to file an Apple Radar.  A possible workaround is to use a different regex parser -- which is "ewww" in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. It makes me less frustrated at c++ std::regex. @KillzoneKid

Comment: Filed to apple. Thanks. @Eljay

Comment: Also, since you said "My gcc version", I had to check.  GNU GCC (g++ `(Homebrew GCC 8.1.0)`) does not exhibit the problem, on macOS.  Via `brew install gcc`.  Apple's dubious "I'm helping!" practice of soft-linking of `gcc` to `clang`, and `g++` to `clang++` strikes again.

Comment: I meant mac's soft linking to clang by "my gcc version". So it's indeed a problem with apple's dylib which the real gcc on mac doesn't use. Right ? @Eljay

Comment: That is correct.  Using `g++-8` with your code, and `otool -L a.out`, I'm seeing dependencies on `libstdc++.6.dylib`, `libSystem.B.dylib`, and `libgcc_s.1.dylib`.