# C++ std::regex not support look ahead backreference

Tags: c++, regex, backreference

I want to match a rule, some name occur like ABA, And A must not equal B.

for example,
'allen_bob_allen' is valid.
'allen_allen_allen'  is not valid.
at https://regexr.com/, I wrote the regex pattern
`([a-z]+)_(?!\1)([a-z]+)_\1` and it work perfectly,

But When I write this in C++, use std::regex,

```
using namespace std;
#include <regex>
int main() {
    std::regex regex_test2("([a-z]+)_(?<!\\1)([a-z]+)_\\1");
    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::regex_error: The expression contained an invalid back reference.`

here is my compiler info:

[image]
Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: FYI: `(?!\1)` is a look**ahead**

Comment: Show the code...

Comment: It might be a bug, also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189107/invalid-back-reference-in-lookahead-in-c-stdregex).

Comment: Your RE [works for me as expected for C++](https://godbolt.org/z/bhTdeo). Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Also your RE has subtle bug for input `a_ab_a`.

Comment: Yet another use of regular expressions where a simple scan of the text would work. Regular expressions are almost always overkill.

Comment: Aren’t you using look-behind in the c++ code regex but in the regex pattern look-ahead?

Comment: Am getting the exact same bug as you with a perfectly valid regex. Looks like this bug is still around...